# Should increase in nodes = increase in query performance?

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

I have a question about node scaling: I am not seeing a performance change when scaling up/down between 1 and 4 nodes in my Spanner instance. I am running some queries that take anywhere from 1-25 seconds, and was expecting improvements with additional nodes. Do I perhaps have the wrong idea about how nodes impact performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding more nodes increases the amount of serving and storage resources, but it doesn't automatically increase the 'sharding' of data. Cloud Spanner splits data based on size and load. It adds more splits as the data size grows or when it detects high read or write load in a split. For more information, see [Database splits](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/schema-and-data-model#database-splits).

Whether adding more nodes will increase your query performance depends on many factors such as your schema design, dataset characteristics, workload, and the type of your queries.

Answer (score 0):

This might be complicated. Google provides [Best Practices](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/instances?_ga=2.182283879.-1988729974.1572956604&_gac=1.251273522.1575369655.EAIaIQobChMI9K3Ym6WZ5gIVh8x3Ch3GwwjMEAAYASAAEgItAvD_BwE#regional-best-practices) which are mentioning 3 factors: design, region and provision. This even not mentioning the node count, so the node number itself is not main factor here. Even in console, when you create new instance you will see note:

[image]

The [link](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/best-practice-list?_ga=2.85942873.-1988729974.1572956604&_gac=1.15011458.1575369655.EAIaIQobChMI9K3Ym6WZ5gIVh8x3Ch3GwwjMEAAYASAAEgItAvD_BwE) in the note also does not mention the node count. So I think first you should use Stockdriver Monitoring and if you see that CPU and Storage utilization is above certain value you can help with adding nodes. Information about the nodes and instances you can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/instances?_ga=2.182283879.-1988729974.1572956604&_gac=1.251273522.1575369655.EAIaIQobChMI9K3Ym6WZ5gIVh8x3Ch3GwwjMEAAYASAAEgItAvD_BwE)

I hope this will help!

Comment: Does an increase in nodes not increase the 'sharding' of data? My thought was since my data is split based on a key, having more nodes would parallelize any queries (at least table scans). Maybe that's not the case though?